# sort array by element[1] & element[2]

Tags: php, sorting

I have data like below (final sort) and I need to sort the lines based

1. on the **first** element **asc** and
2. then by the **second** element **desc** and
3. then by the **third** element **desc**

as elements are separated by `.`

```
edumate_3rdparty.20110209.1000.hourly.sql
edumate_3rdparty.20110209.0800.hourly.sql
edumate_3rdparty.20101209.Thursday.daily.sql
moodle_acots.20110130.1600.hourly.sql
moodle_acots.20110105.0800.hourly.sql
moodle_tara.20110316.1200.hourly.sql
moodle_tags.20110222.1000.hourly.sql
moodle_tags.20110208.1801.hourly.sql
moodle_will.20110302.1100.hourly.sql
moodle_wollo.20101031.October.4.weekly.sql
```

how can I do that in php?

Comment: Well... are you worried of how fast it will do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example on how you could sort that data-set.

```
<?php
$a=array();
$a[]=explode('.','edumate_3rdparty.20110209.1000.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','edumate_3rdparty.20110209.0800.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','edumate_3rdparty.20101209.Thursday.daily.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','moodle_acots.20110130.1600.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','moodle_acots.20110105.0800.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','moodle_tara.20110316.1200.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','moodle_tags.20110222.1000.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','moodle_tags.20110208.1801.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','moodle_will.20110302.1100.hourly.sql');
$a[]=explode('.','moodle_wollo.20101031.October.4.weekly.sql');
shuffle($a);
// all you need is this function
function special($a, $b){
    if($a[0]!=$b[0])return strcmp($a[0],$b[0]);// asc
    if($a[1]!=$b[1])return strcmp($b[1],$a[1]);// desc
    return strcmp($b[2],$a[2]);// desc
}
usort($a,'special');
// and maybe the above call
echo'<pre>';
foreach($a as $id=>$value)
    $a[$id]=implode('.',$a[$id]);
var_dump($a);
?>
```

I used Paul's explode idea to get the test scenario going. So thumb's up to him :)

Comment: Updated with some implodes to get the strings back to the way they were, although I highly doubt the data wasn't already an array to begin with.

Comment: @Khez: doesn't work as desired. The output gives me `"moodle_acots.20110105.0800.hourly.sql", "moodle_acots.20110130.1600.hourly.sql"` where it should be the opposite. 20110130 > 20110105

Comment: how can I make it sort by 3rd element if the first two are the same?

Comment: Didn't notice the DESC in your OP. Try `if($a[1]!=$b[1])return strcmp($b[1],$a[1]);`. Updated. It already sorts by the third element if the first two are the same.

Comment: e x a c t l y   as I wanted it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First I would make the data into an array using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).  Then i would sort it using [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

usort enables you to provide the comparison function for the sort.